# What happens if you check for < condition in ternary or conditional operator(x < y ? num1 : num2) in c, but the input value is equal

Tags: c, gcc, conditional-operator, relational-operators

So I was just trying to write a C code for comparing numbers, which one of the three number is largest and which one is the smallest.

Then I found that I can use the ternary operator (ex: `x < y ? num1 : num2),` so I thought yeah okay this will work and then I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int num1, num2, num3, largest, smallest;

printf("Enter three integers: ");
scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

//largest among three integers.

largest = num1 > num2 ? (num1 > num3 ? num1 : num3) : (num2 > num3 ? num2 : num3);
printf("\nThe largest among the three is: %d", largest);

//smallest among three integers

smallest = num1 < num2 ? (num1 < num3 ? num1 : num3) : (num2 < num3 ? num2 : num3);
printf("\nThe smallest among the three is: %d", smallest);

return 0;
}
```

So, if I give input like num1 = 10, num2 = 20 and num3 = 30, then the output is

```
Enter three integers: 10 20 30

The largest among the three is: 30
The smallest among the three is: 10
```

But what happens when all these numbers are equal? Will the condition of the Ternary operator be true or false?

```
Enter three integers: 20 20 20

The largest among the three is: 20
The smallest among the three is: 20
```

I don't know what the condition but the program works fine nothing wrong the output is correct.

I am using this on windows 10 latest and gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

I am sorry if this is a lame question but I didn't found anything about this.

Comment: `<` means "less than and not equal". `<=` means "less than or equal". It is standard mathematical notation.

Comment: If you have the condition `a < b` when both `a` and `b` are equal, the result would be what is expected: `a < b` is `false`. The `<` operator is a strict less-than operator, just as in math.

Comment: if the the numbers are equal, `num1 < num2` results in `false` - just the same as in a regular `if` condition

Comment: thank you guys for clearing my doubt. it helped. you guys are awesome

Comment: If the numbers are equal, you don't mind, because you can select any of them, they have the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` larger operator is `true` only if the *left* value is **larger** than the *rigth* value. Otherwise it will be **false**

> Will the condition of the Ternary operator be true or false?

```
n = x > y ? x : y;
```

`n` will be assigned with the value of `x` if `x` is **larger** than `y`, otherwise (including the case when `x == y`) it will be assigned with the value of `y`

Answer (score 0):

If the first expression of the conditional operator evaluates to false then the result of the conditional operator is the value of the third expression.

For example in this statement

```
largest = num1 > num2 ? (num1 > num3 ? num1 : num3) : (num2 > num3 ? num2 : num3);
```

if `num1` is not greater than `num2` (that is the expression with the relational operator `num1 > num2` evaluates to false) then this (third) expression evaluates

```
(num2 > num3 ? num2 : num3)
```

Again if `num2` is not greater than `num3` then the result of this expression and of the whole enclosing expression is the value of `num3`,

Answer (score 0):

Generally, boolean algebra goes: the opposite of `a > b` ("a greater than b") is `a <= b` ("a less or equal to b").

If you want to cover larger than, smaller than and equal, then you'd need something like this pseudo code:

```
(a < b) ? smaller : ( (a > b) ? larger : equal )
```

Which is just an obscure and unreadable way of the equivalent preferred code:

```
if(a < b)
{}
else if(a > b)
{}
else // equal
{}
```

Always use `if-else if` chains over `?:` chains unless you have specialized requirements, such as when writing function-like macros.